# How to find the string in large description value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 column ID and description.I want to get the only  mailid for each ID column.

```
ID  Description
1   I have 2 mailID please note this mai1: anto1@gmail.com and mai1: anto2@gmail.com and mai1: anto3@gmail.com abbaaabbbbbbb.
2   I have 2 mailID please note this mai1: sample1@gmail.com and mai1: sample2@gmail.com and mai1: sample3@gmail.com abbaaabbbbbbb.
```

Expected output

```
ID  Description
1   anto1@gmail.com
1   anto2@gmail.com
1   anto3@gmail.com
2   sample1@gmail.com
2   sample2@gmail.com
2   sample3@gmail.com
```

I have tried this below query.

```
SELECT id,Description
FROM sample_for
WHERE CHARINDEX('@', Description) > 0
```

But please provide the alternate valid query.

Comment: You need all the words that have @ in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this...

### Test Data

```
Declare @table TABLE(ID int , Description Varchar(8000))
INsert into @table values
(1 ,  'I have 2 mailID please note this mai1: anto1@gmail.com and mai1: anto2@gmail.com and mai1: anto3@gmail.com abbaaabbbbbbb'),
(2 ,  'I have 2 mailID please note this mai1: sample1@gmail.com and mai1: sample2@gmail.com and mai1: sample3@gmail.com abbaaabbbbbbb')
```

### Query

```
Select ID
     ,LEFT(RTRIM(LTRIM(Emails)) , CHARINDEX(' ' , RTRIM(LTRIM(Emails)))) Emails
from 
(
SELECT t.ID 
          ,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') Emails
FROM   
    (SELECT Cast ('<X>' + Replace(Description, ':', '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) AS Data
            ,ID
    FROM    @table
    ) AS t CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/X') AS Split(a)
 )a 
Where a.emails LIKE '%@%'
```

### Result Set

```
╔════╦════════════════════╗
║ ID ║       Emails       ║
╠════╬════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ anto1@gmail.com    ║
║  1 ║ anto2@gmail.com    ║
║  1 ║ anto3@gmail.com    ║
║  2 ║ sample1@gmail.com  ║
║  2 ║ sample2@gmail.com  ║
║  2 ║ sample3@gmail.com  ║
╚════╩════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @xml xml
--- Remove from here...    
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1, 'I have 2 mailID please note this mai1: anto1@gmail.com and mai1: anto2@gmail.com and mai1: anto3@gmail.com abbaaabbbbbbb.'),
(2, 'I have 2 mailID please note this mai1: sample1@gmail.com and mai1: sample2@gmail.com and mai1: sample3@gmail.com abbaaabbbbbbb.')
) as t(ID, [Description])
)
-- To here
SELECT @xml = (
    SELECT CAST('<i id="' + CAST(id as nvarchar(10)) + '"><a>' +REPLACE([Description],' ','</a><a>') +'</a></i>' as xml)
    FROM cte -- here change cte to your table name
    FOR XML PATH ('')
)

SELECT  t.v.value('../@id', 'int') as id,
        t.v.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') as email
FROM @xml.nodes('/i/a') as t(v)
WHERE t.v.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') like '%@%'
```

Output:

```
id  email
1   anto1@gmail.com
1   anto2@gmail.com
1   anto3@gmail.com
2   sample1@gmail.com
2   sample2@gmail.com
2   sample3@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Description, CHARINDEX('mai1:', Description) + 5, CHARINDEX('mai1:', Description))
FROM Table
WHERE Description LIKE '%mai1:%'
  AND CHARINDEX('mai1:', Description) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your trying but this query not help for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not as robust a solution due to my limited knowledge of SQL server (would probably do this with REGEXP_SUBSTR in oracle).  It's limited to 3 or less emails and would have to be expanded manually if more are needed. One of the other solutions posted are probably better but just wanted to put this on here as well:

```
with temp(ID,  Description)
as(
select 1, 'I have 2 mailID please note this mai1: anto1@gmail.com and mai1: anto2@gmail.com and mai1: anto3@gmail.com abbaaabbbbbbb.' union all
select 2, 'I have 2 mailID please note this mai1: sample1@gmail.com and mai1: sample2@gmail.com and mai1: sample3@gmail.com abbaaabbbbbbb.'
)

SELECT
 ID,
 EMAIL
from (
  select
  ID,
  case when start1 > 0 then substring(Description, start1+2, end1-start1+2) end email1,
  case when start2 > 0 then substring(Description, start2+2, end2-start2+2) end email2,
  case when start3 > 0 then substring(Description, start3+2, end3-start3+2) end email3
  from (
    select ID, Description,
      start1 = ISNULL(CHARINDEX(':', Description, 0),0),
      start2 = ISNULL(CHARINDEX(':', Description, CHARINDEX(':', Description, 0)+1),0),
      start3 = ISNULL(CHARINDEX(':', Description, CHARINDEX(':', Description, CHARINDEX(':', Description, 0)+1)+1),0),
      end1 = ISNULL(CHARINDEX('.com', Description, 0),0),
      end2 = ISNULL(CHARINDEX('.com', Description, CHARINDEX('.com', Description, 0)+4),0),
      end3 = ISNULL(CHARINDEX('.com', Description, CHARINDEX('.com', Description, CHARINDEX('.com', Description, 0)+4)+4),0)
    from temp  ) as pos
    ) temp1
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES
  (email1),
  (email2),
  (email3)
) temp2 (email)
where EMAIL is NOT NULL
```